# Query JavaScript Object group by

Tags: javascript, grouping, alasql

I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":3},{"a":2,"b":4},{"a":2,"b":5}]
```

I want to group this object field 'a' and want something like this:

```
[{"a":1,"values":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":3}]},{"a":2,"values":[{"a":2,"b":4},{"a":2,"b":5}]}]
```

I have a JavaScript array of more than few thousands elements. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore JS provides nice methods for structuring your models and grouping/filtering them.

http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var data = [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":3},{"a":2,"b":4},{"a":2,"b":5}];

var res = alasql('SELECT a, ARRAY(_) AS [values] FROM ? GROUP BY a',[data]);
```

Here `ARRAY(_)` is a special aggregation function which saves current record(`_`) into the array with name `values`.

You can play with this example [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/d4e1Ltoo/2/).