# AngularJS Array - How to add amount if same category

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

How to add the amount if they have same category in angular and remove the duplicate entry.

For example:

```
self.lineDetails = [{id:'0',category:'AAA',amount:'500'},
                    {id:'1',category:'BBB',amount:'200'},
                    {id:'2',category:'AAA',amount:'300'}]
```

Desired Output:

```
self.newLineDetails = [{id:'0',category:'AAA',amount:'800'},
                    {id:'1',category:'BBB',amount:'200'}]
```

Comment: You want to group the data, for that you can use the third party libraries, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405937/query-javascript-object-group-by

Comment: @PM. I don't want to use a third party library. I was hoping the angularjs would be enough.

Comment: You don't need AngularJS specifically to solve this problem. It can be done using plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the angularjs filter groupBy

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
 $scope.data = [{id:'0',category:'AAA',amount:'500'},
                    {id:'1',category:'BBB',amount:'200'},
                    {id:'2',category:'AAA',amount:'300'}];

 $scope.getAmountSum = function(items) {
   return items
    .map(function(x) { return x.amount; })
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); });
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, items) in data | groupBy: 'category'">
      category: {{items[0].category}}, amount: {{getAmountSum(items)}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: items.map is not a function
    at Object.self.getAmountSum

Comment: look at the demo above

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a map sort of json in angular js as :

```
self.lineDetails = [{id:'0',category:'AAA',amount:'500'},
                    {id:'1',category:'BBB',amount:'200'},
                    {id:'2',category:'AAA',amount:'300'}];
self.lineDetailsMap = {};
angular.forEach(self.lineDetails, function(lineDetail)    {
     if(self.lineDetailsMap[lineDetail.category] !== undefined)    {
          var lineDetailOld = self.lineDetailsMap[lineDetail.category] ;
          lineDetail.amount = parseInt(lineDetailOld.amount) + parseInt(lineDetail.amount);
     }
     self.lineDetailsMap[lineDetail.category] = lineDetail;

});
```

Now you can iterate upon this map to fetch the new list:

```
self.newLineDetails = [];
angular.forEach(self.lineDetailsMap,function(value,key)     {
    self.newLineDetails.push(value);
});
```

Let me know if you get any issues

Comment: self.newLineDetails is coming up blank.

Comment: Can you please check what is getting populated in  self.lineDetailsMap

Comment: it generates an array but the amount is wrong.

Comment: I tried using lineDetailsMap instead but the amount is still wrong.

Comment: Can you show what is getting stored in map

Comment: lineDetails before adding your solution:

0:{Id:310,CategoryId:"G66",Amount:1124}
1:{Id:311,CategoryId:"G66",Amount:4551}
2:{Id:312,CategoryId:"D52",Amount:56}



lineDetails after adding your solution:
0:{Id:310,CategoryId:"G66",Amount:14777}
1:{Id:311,CategoryId:"G66",Amount:4551}
2:{Id:312,CategoryId:"D52",Amount:56}

lineDetailsMap:
D52:{Id:312,CategoryId:"D52",Amount:56}
G66:{Id:310,CategoryId:"G66",Amount:14777}

Comment: Have edited the code..can you try this one and let me know...

Comment: thanks for the effort but it's still blank. I already got an answer. thanks again.

Comment: So, sorry that couldn't help on time but glad to know you got other solution, however, I have corrected the solution again...it can help other users in future :)